# Selected name from List box not Saving

Tags: ms-access

Super new to MS Access and trying to create a database.

ListData
Contains
ID = Autonumber = TxtID below
Full Name

code when ListData is clicked

```
Private Sub ListData_Click()
With ListData
    txtID.Value = .Column(0)    
    txtEmployeeID.Value = .Column(1)
    txtFirstName.Value = .Column(2)
    txtMiddleName.Value = .Column(3)
    txtLastName.Value = .Column(4)  
End With
End Sub
```

The txt changes when a name is selected in the List Data box. However, **it does not let me save the *changed values* of texts from row 2 onwards of the List Box**.

When I try to save the info I get the error

> "The changes requested to the table were not successful because they
> would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or
> relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain
> duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit
> duplicate entries and try again."

I find a List Box easier to use than continuous form with List Data.

Comment: What table is form bound to and what table does listbox pull from? From the error message, sounds like same table used for both.

Comment: both are bound to same table. what I'm doing is, a full name list on the left side then on the right their associated information such as ID(autonumber)< should not be editable, EmployeeID etc...   I want to click on the name, display data, change the data then press save. it only works if row 1 is selected on the list box. on row two onwards it gives the error.

Comment: Nothing presented here makes sense. You want to click on listbox item and save that data to a record? But why, there is already a record with that data. You probably get error because with any selection in listbox, code is trying to save data to first record in table and that causes duplication when selecting any but first item in listbox.

Comment: it's a form. Left side is a list box with names. right side are field names. think of it like  contact list.  when I select a name on the left. the right side will show the details.   then i can edit the details should I want to. save it then select a new name.  I am a total newbie. probably the code is incorrect. is there a different code. I believe the code I have only is only for show. not opening the record itself

Comment: If you are editing data by typing into textboxes of a bound form, no code is needed. Typed info will pass directly to table. If you are using posted code to fill textboxes of form, then form cannot be bound or must be on a new record row - otherwise you will edit existing record, which in this case is always the same record. Code you should have for listbox is to apply filter to form. Access provides a design wizard for that when first creating listbox or combobox or write the code yourself. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: Thanks Mate, I should have created the fields first, then the list box. I did it backwards and it resulted in incorrect info flow.  it works now as expected. :)